# Leopard-like dock for Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows, dock

I want a dock like MacOSX Leopard's, for my Windows 7.

Required features:

- display *all* open Windows, not just minimized ones
- when I maximize Windows, I don't want them to go under the dock. The bottom part of my screen should be empty except for the dock there.
- a "start menu" button
- a clock of some sort

So far I've tried RocketDock and RK Launcher. They lack some of the above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tried [ObjectDock](http://www.stardock.com/products/objectdock/) yet? The full version has more features than the Mac's last time I used it.

Comment: Works perfectly, thanks! Do you by chance know how to add a small margin between the dock and the maximized windows above it?

Comment: @monov: Try DesktopCoral with full transparency http://www.donationcoder.com/Software/Mouser/desktopcoral/index.html